Lead conversion issue
I'm troubleshooting an issue involving converting leads.  For leads associated with the Standard record type, SF displays the following dialog when I click on the Converted chevron in the path and then click [Select Converted Status]:

However, for leads associated with the custom Digital record type, the same steps display the Convert dialog instead:

I need to change something so that Standard leads and Digital leads have the same underlying convert process.  What setting(s) are controlling this?

The issue was the page layout didn't have the [Convert] button selected, either as a standard button or the mobile action version.  When I included both versions of the button, I get the desired behavior.
